# Will Diablo 3 run better on my Mac if I play in Windows 7 via Boot Camp?

Tags: diablo-iii, macos, boot-camp

*Diablo III* doesn't play very well for me in OS X, even with most graphics quality settings set to low.

A Battle.net support article says that [the minimum system requirements in Windows 7 are lower than Mac OS X](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-system-requirements).

If I play *Diablo III* in Windows 7 via Boot Camp, is the game performance going to be better than playing in OS X natively?

Comment: Hello, Jojas. Questions about "Can I run this?" or "Which will run this better?" are considered Too Localized for our site.

Comment: I've had better frame rates on W7 than I did on OS X, but overall I think you need a better dedicated graphics card, because a Intel HD Graphics 3000 integrated graphics card just [can't handle the graphics](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-system-requirements).

Comment: If you're playing the game before it is fully downloaded, then the performance will be terrible.  My Mac (similar to yours) ran *much* better after I let the download complete.  It was a painful wait, but worth it.

Comment: @Krazer I think so, It's really bad news for me :-(

Comment: @PatLudwig I have play the game after successful installation. Did you have any suggestion to improve game running under my Mac?

Comment: This question [is being discussed on Meta.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4688/is-comparing-the-performance-of-games-running-under-different-operating-systems) I feel it should be reopened.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR version: Yes, Diablo III runs better in Windows than in Mac OS X.**

---

I have a [Mid 2011, 27" iMac](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP623) (Specifically, with a Core i5, 2.6GHz CPU and a Radeon HD 6770M graphics card). I installed Diablo 3 in both OS X and Windows 7 and ran a few simple tests by loading up a character who was parked at the Act II starting area.

[image: The location I used]

### Default settings

The default/suggested video settings were the same on both platforms:

- 1920 × 1080 resolution
- High texture quality
- Medium shadow quality
- High physics
- High clutter density
- Anti-aliasing on

### High resolution

My 27" iMac's display has a native resolution of 2560 × 1440. I did a separate set of tests at this resolution as well.

### Low FX

Changing the texture, shadow, physics, and clutter settings only had minor effects (at least on my machine), but I did notice a significant boost by disabling anti-aliasing and turning on the "Low FX" mode.

### Results

(In the chart below, *D* means default settings, *L* means default settings with Low FX mode enabled and anti-aliasing off.)

```
             1920× D  1920× L  2560× D  2560× L
             --------------------------------
       OS X: 34 FPS   39 FPS   23 FPS   27 FPS
    Windows: 47 FPS   53 FPS   27 FPS   35 FPS
Improvement:   ~38%     ~35%     ~17%     ~29%
```

I didn't exhaustively test every combination of settings and resolutions, but based on these results, I'm willing to state that **yes, Diablo III runs better in Windows**.

Comment: Not only that, but even now, in 2014, the textures' resolution is somewhat lowered (it's pretty visible with the human eye), on OS X, even at the maximum settings possible.

Comment: As a general impression about gaming on OSX, almost all the multi platform games work a lot better on Windows. Given the fact that most multi platform games run the same on Linux like they work on Windows, on properly made cross-platform games (I mean games that use the same API OpenGL, and not DX on Windows and OpenGL on UNIX-based systems), I'm pretty sure that OS X problems are due to the bad drivers, and the lack of will from Apple to work closer with AMD/nvidia to push better drivers for OS X.